# stored a byte in a register to variable whose address is stored in another register

Tags: mips, cpu-registers

I want to store a char to a variable whose address is stored in $t7 registers.To be able to do that I though `sb $t6, $t7` could be done however I get an error ın this line. I want to learn my opinion is wrong or I made mistake in somewhere else ? thanks in advance

by the way t6 holds the address of var1 variable.

Answer (score 1):

A store command takes an offset, in this case 0:

```
sb $t6, 0($t7)
```